# Xml isn't correctly interpreted by Adobe Build

Tags: xml, build, permissions, adobe, config

I've create a config.xml to configure the setup of my app via Adobe Build.
I based my file on this document (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "app.katho.midzomerrun"
    version   = "1.0.0">

<name>MidZomerRun Beta</name>

<description>
Dit is de officiële app voor MidZomerRun 2013
</description>

<!--
    Enable individual API permissions by defining each here.
    The 'device' permission is required for the 'deviceready' event.
-->
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />

<!--
    If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
    following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
    permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
-->

<!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
<preference name="phonegap-version"           value="2.5.0" />
<!-- all: current version of PhoneGap -->
<preference name="orientation"                value="portrait" />
<!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
<preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />
<!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
<preference name="fullscreen"                 value="false" />
<!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
<preference name="webviewbounce"              value="false" />
<!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
<preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />
<!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
<preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="true" />
<!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />
<!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
<preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />
<!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
<preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />
<!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />
<!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
<preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />
<!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="7" />
<!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
<preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />
<!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->

<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>
<!-- allow local pages -->
<!--
    <access origin="http://phonegap.com" />                    - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
    <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but     including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
    <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows     http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
  -->

  </widget>
```

Why doesn't give Adobe Build my permissions? The file is correctly validated, and it's conform the info on this page (https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml)

Can somebody help me out?
Thanks!